# borderRadius in react-native-autocomplete-input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autocomplete

I want to create AutoComplete as in the image, how could I do?

[image]

Below example of my current implementation,

```
inputContainerStyle: {
   minHeight: 0,
   borderWidth: 0,
   borderBottomWidth: 0,
   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
   fontSize: Sizes.textBig,
   fontFamily: Fonts.regular,
}
```

Comment: Dados do pegamento is the list that u want ?,

Comment: I want the autocomplete to look like these inputs

Comment: You should post not only the styles code but also View's, and maybe other related code you use. Did you try to test examples from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input ?

Answer (score 0):

From the styling you posted it seems like you missed some properties. Have you tried adding width, height and borderRadius properties to the container ?

Comment: Yes I added, but it remains a rectangle

Comment: Could you please show a snippet of the component itself